# What books are there to read demonstrations?

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

I have been searching in the web for books with logic demonstrations of equations, formulas, theorems, etc. The problem is, I have found them, but they include too much calculation. I would like to read a book where you can find an explanation and logical demonstrations of formulas, equations, etc. By this I mean, for example:

In the formula of permutation, is $n!$, because when you choose the first element, you only have left $n - 1$ elements, after when you choose the second, you have only left $n - 2$n, because you have already chosen 2 elements. This is what I want, a demonstration and logical explanation, to really understand a formula / theorem / equation, and not just replace variables.

So, could you recommend books? where there are logical explanations of many formulas?

Comment: This is not a good question. What you're describing is just a well-written math textbook.

Comment: You are asking for a book explaining the rudiments of mathematics proofs, where many related questions are suggested in the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

I would just look through elementary books on probability and combinatorics in a library until you find what works best for you. A fairly well known such book written for strong high school students is [**Mathematics of Choice**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883856158) by Ivan Niven (see [here](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/mathematics-of-choice-or-how-to-count-without-counting) also).

[This online reference](https://www.wileyindia.com/media/pdf/047126296X.pdf) might also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You may have difficulty finding books that that do not include "too much calculation," as you stated. Often the author of a text on combinatorics is a combinatorialist, and they generally enjoy calculations.

That being said, a book that lets *you* figure out many of the calculations is Bogart's *Combinatorics Through Guided Discovery*. The text is [freely available online](http://bogart.openmathbooks.org/), and recommended by the American Institute for Mathematics as an open text.

Answer (score 0):

Given the very broad context of your question, I recommend "[How to prove it. An structured approach.](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL3413317M/How_to_prove_it)" by D. Velleman. It teaches about mathematical reasoning and demonstrations in general.